# Which database isolation we should use for the same , and which isolation level is best?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

In SQL server 2005,

I have so many stored procedure , some of used update table records with transactions, some used for get the table records.

when the one SP is calling in one seetion which are updaing the table records, at thet time the if i run another SP for getiing table data , then it should be run without waiting, what i need to do?

Which database isolation we should use for the same , and which isolation level is best?

It can be poosible with "transalation snapshot isolation level". but it will pick that old snapshot data in Teampdb database, which can be degrade performance.

what you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

`READ COMMITTED` is the default transaction isolation level in SQL Server.

Use of any other isolation level (to me, anyway) constitutes a *[code smell](http://www.google.com/#q=code+smell)* — to me, at least — that requires some real justification, with the possible exception of the limited use of `READ UNCOMMITTED` in certain contexts.

Comment: Just leave it at `READ COMMITTED` unless you have a real justification for another isolation level. If you are encountering significant blocking, you probably need to review the design of your transactions.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`SNAPSHOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcbchxcb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) isolation level. The best is to turn on READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT at the database level, which will silently transform all the default READ COMMITTED transactions into snapshot transactions.

The reasons why SNAPSHOT is best for applications, specially for applications that can run into blocking due to concurrency issues, are countless, and the benefits are endless. It is true that SNAPSHOT isolation occurs a [cost in resources used](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175492.aspx), but unless you measured and find conclusive evidence that is the row version store that is causing the problems, you cannot dismiss it upfront.

The one isolation level one should never use is UNCOMMITTED. That is asking for trouble. [Dirty reads are inconsistent reads](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlcat/archive/2007/02/01/previously-committed-rows-might-be-missed-if-nolock-hint-is-used.aspx).

REPEATABLE and SERIALIZABLE have extremely narrow use cases and you'll most likely never need them. Unfortunately SERIALIZABLE is abused by the .Net System.Transactions and by the MTS/COM+ so a lot of applications end up using it (andf having huge scalability issues because of it), although it is not required.

Answer (score 0):

If first transaction updated data in some table then second will wait anyway to get this data (except READ UNCOMMITTED isolation level, but in this case you can have very inconsistent data).